# Google+ Platform failed to run sample android app PlusSampleActivity

Tags: android, google-plus

Followed the exact steps on https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android. Launched the sample PlusSampleActivity on my Nexus 7. When clicked "sign in", the error "an internal error has occurred" was shown. I traced back and found that the function

```
mLastConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), mRequestCode);
```

throws the error. I also did not find any place in the sample project to enter my own key.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. To run the sample app, the package name CANNOT be your own project, but rather "com.google.android.gms.samples.plus".